# Is this rearrangement in carbocation possible?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation

Generally, in the following type of reactions, positive charge on $\alpha$-Carbon causes ring expansion, but in the following example positive charge is formed on $\beta$-Carbon and the cation is cyclo-propyl methyl.

[image]
So is the above rearrangement even practically possible?

Comment: For what it's worth, there are no reports of this reaction in the scientific literature.

Answer (score -3):

yes,  the rearrangement in carbocation is possible depending upon the condition of reaction and the stability of the new carbocation formed
 eg- the general order of stabilty for carbocation is 3degree >2degree > 1degree 
NOTE- the stability of a carbocation depends on aromaticity resonance hyperconjucation inductive effect and sometime ring expansion also occurs